Pass optional weight argument to model.frame
I'm trying to program a function that takes an optional weights argument and passes it to model.frame:
test <- function(ff, weights, data) {
  mm <- model.frame(ff, data, weights=weights)
  y <- model.response(mm)
  x <- mm[, 2]
  w <- mm[, 3:ncol(mm)-1]
  wt <- model.weights(mm)
  mat <- cbind(y, x, w, wt)
  return(sum(mat))
}

I'm getting an error that says
> test(ff, weight=wt, data=dtaw)
Error in model.frame.default(ff, data, weights = weights) : 
  invalid type (closure) for variable '(weights)'
Called from: model.frame.default(ff, data, weights = weights)

here is how to reproduce it
dtaw <- data.frame(y = runif(100))
dtaw$x <- runif(100)
dtaw$w1 <- runif(100)
dtaw$w2 <- runif(100)
dtaw$wt <- runif(100)

ff <- y ~ x + w1 + w2
test(ff, weight=wt, data=dtaw)

Also, is there better way to extract the first rhs variable, and the rest of the rhs variables from the model.frame mm in the function test?

Here are three alternatives.  (1) assumes an unevaluated expression  for the weights representing the column name, (2) passes the value of weights rather than naming the column and (3) passes a character string naming the weights column.
1) Using the inputs in the Note at the end,  use substitute to get the unevaluated weights variable name, convert it to a name it if is character and then call model.frame using do.call.  If passing a character string the string should either be a character literal or else call test2 using do.call as shown. We have also added a default value of NULL to weights since the question indicates that it is optional.  The line marked ## can be omitted if passing a character string is not needed.
test2 <- function(ff, weights = NULL, data) {
  weights <- substitute(weights)
  if (is.character(weights)) weights <- as.name(weights) ##
  mf <- do.call("model.frame", list(ff, dtaw, weights = weights))
  sum(mf)
}

test2(ff, wt, dtaw)
## [1] 247.6418

test2(ff, "wt", dtaw)
## [1] 247.6418

v <- "wt"
do.call("test2", list(ff, v, dtaw))
## [1] 247.6418

test2(ff, data = dtaw)
## [1] 199.1028

2) Another possibility is to write it like this in which case the
actual value of weights must be passed:
test3 <- function(ff, weights = NULL, data) {
  mf <- do.call("model.frame", list(ff, dtaw, weights = weights))
  sum(mf)
}

test3(ff, dtaw$wt, dtaw)
## [1] 247.6418

test3(ff, data = dtaw)
## [1] 199.1028

3) This alternative passes a character string naming the weights column in the data.  Unlike test2 in (1) the character string may be contained in a variable without using do.call.
test4 <- function(ff, weights = NULL, data) {
      if (!is.null(weights)) weights <- data[[weights]]
      mf <- do.call("model.frame", list(ff, dtaw, weights = weights))
      sum(mf)
    }
test4(ff, "wt", data = dtaw)
## [1] 247.6418

v <- "wt"
test4(ff, v, data = dtaw)
## [1] 247.6418

test4(ff, data = dtaw)
## [1] 199.1028

Also note that in the question that 3:ncol(mm)-1 should be 3:(ncol(mm)-1) although this is just an aside and the main problem is the one addressed above.
Note
We show the inputs reproducibly by adding set.seed
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
dtaw <- data.frame(y = runif(n))
dtaw$x <- runif(n)
dtaw$w1 <- runif(n)
dtaw$w2 <- runif(n)
dtaw$wt <- runif(n)
ff <- y ~ x + w1 + w2


I like your test2 best.

The problem is that model.frame() uses non-standard evaluation to add the weights to the result.  It is looking for "weights" in the dataframe (which doesn't have it), then in the environment of the formula (which is the global environment).  It never looks in the evaluation frame of your function.
To fix this, you could add the column to the dataframe.  This has the disadvantage that you might have another column with that name, and things would go bad, but that's hard to avoid, except by tricky manipulation of the call to model.frame() (see lm() source for example), but I wouldn't do that.  Here's a simple version:
test <- function(ff, weights, data) {
  # Add the weights to the data.  Use a name that is unlikely to collide
  # with an existing name
  data$test_weights <- weights

  # Use the new name `test_weights` in the call to model.frame
  mm <- model.frame(ff, data, weights=test_weights)

  y <- model.response(mm)
  x <- mm[, 2]
  w <- mm[, 3:ncol(mm)-1]
  wt <- model.weights(mm)
  mat <- cbind(y, x, w, wt)
  return(sum(mat))
}

You need to call this with weights specified using an expression that doesn't use non-standard evaluation, e.g.
test(ff, weight=dtaw$wt, data=dtaw)

